# Python: Assign one element from a list to elements in other list

Tags: python, list, assign

i got two lists:

```
L_1 = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value 4']
L_2 = [['Value1', 'Value1_01'], ['', 'Value1_02'], ['', 'Value1_03'], 
       ['Value2', 'Value2_01'], ['', 'Value2_02'], 
       ['Value3', 'Value3_01'], ['', 'Value3_02'], ['', 'Value3_03'], ['', 'Value3_04']
       ['Value4', 'Value4_01'], ['', 'Value4_02']]
```

from this i need a list that assign the elements Value1 to Value4 to their 'littler sisters'.
should look like this:

```
L1 =   ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value 4']
L_res = [['Value1_01', 'Value1_02', 'Value1_03'], 
         ['Value2_01', 'Value2_02'], 
         ['Value3_01', 'Value3_02', 'Value3_03', 'Value3_04']
         ['Value4_01', 'Value4_02']
```

i need to count where 
`L2[i][0] == '' or L2[i][0] == L1[i]` and then give me the values from `L2[i][1]` and put it to `L_res`

Hopefully someone of you understand the problem and has got an idea to solve the problem.

I really appreciate this

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
L_res = []
for i in L_2:
   if i[0]:
       L_res.append([i[1]])
   else:
       L_res[-1].append(i[1])

L_res
# [['Value1_01', 'Value1_02', 'Value1_03'],
#  ['Value2_01', 'Value2_02'],
#  ['Value3_01', 'Value3_02', 'Value3_03', 'Value3_04'],
#  ['Value4_01', 'Value4_02']]
```